# Turning ON and OFF the LEDs on PIC24. I do not see a problem with the code. However the state machine does not seem to execute right

Tags: c, embedded

The problem is in the case statement BLINK_PRESSED, the code I have builds and flashes on to the micro controller fine, everything executes fine until the BLINK_PRESSED state, its just that when I reach the BLINK_PRESSED state, I expect the while loop to blink the LED continuously until the PB_RELEASED() makes the condition false and then exits the while loop and move on to the other states . But, what happens is, in the BLINK_PRESSED state, LED just stays ON continuously rather than blinking and the logic does not execute.However, I tested the logic in MPLAB Sim by toggling the inputs of the state machine which checks out the logic but fails to run it in real time on the HW. Hope this clearly explains the issue. Thanks much for your response.

The problem I am facing is in case BLINK_PRESSED:
while(PB_PRESSED()) line, my understanding is that while should return true as long as the PB is pressed, else should change state. Please help understand why the while statement seems to be an issue. Thanks in advance!!!

Steps:

1.Turn LED On. On press and release, turn LED off, goto 2.

2. After press and release, blink 2 times and freeze on.
3. After press and release, if Switch input is 0, goto 1 else goto next step.
4. Blink when pressed and held down. After release and press, continue blinking. After another release, goto 5.
5. Blink rapidly. On press and release, goto 1

   ```
    # define PB_RELEASED()  (_RB13 == 1)  //push button released
                # define PB_PRESSED()   (_RB13 == 0)    // Push button pressed
                #define LED1 (_LATB14)     //led1 state as output
                #define SW              (_RB12) // Switch as input,
   ```

   /*The input/output port configurations are not shown*/

   ```
                typedef enum  { //states
                  STATE_RELEASED1,
                  STATE_PRESSED1,
                  STATE_RELEASED2,
                  STATE_PRESSED2,
                  STATE_RELEASED3_BLINK,
                  STATE_PRESSED3,
                  STATE_RELEASED4,   
                  BLINK_PRESSED,
                  STATE_RELEASED5,
                  STATE_PRESSED4,
                  STATE_RELEASED6,
                  STATE_RELEASED7, 
                  STATE_RELEASED8,          
                } state_t;

                void update_state(void) { //state machine
                    static state_t e_state = STATE_RELEASED1;
                    uint8_t toggles = 0;
                    switch(e_state){
                        case STATE_RELEASED1:
                            LED1 = 1; //Starts in LED On
                            if(PB_PRESSED()){ //PB is pressed Step1
                                e_state = STATE_PRESSED1;
                            }
                            break;

                        case STATE_PRESSED1:
                            if(PB_RELEASED()){ //PB is releases Step1
                                e_state = STATE_RELEASED2;
                            }
                            break;

                        case STATE_RELEASED2:
                            LED1 = 0; //LED goes off per step 1
                            if(PB_PRESSED()){ //PB is pressed step2
                                e_state = STATE_PRESSED2;
                            }
                            break;

                        case STATE_PRESSED2:
                            if(PB_RELEASED()){ //PB is released Step2
                                e_state = STATE_RELEASED3_BLINK;
                            }
                            break;

                        case STATE_RELEASED3_BLINK:
                            while(toggles < 4){ // On, Off, On, Off per step2
                                LED1 = !LED1;
                                DELAY_MS(250);
                                toggles++;
                            }
                            LED1 = !LED1; //Freeze On per Step 2
                            e_state = STATE_PRESSED3;
                            break;

                        case STATE_PRESSED3:
                            if(PB_PRESSED()){ //PB is pressed again per step3
                                e_state = STATE_RELEASED4;
                            }
                            break;

                        case STATE_RELEASED4:
                            if(PB_RELEASED() && !SW){ //PB is released and sw is checked step3
                                e_state = STATE_RELEASED1;
                            }
                            if(PB_RELEASED() && SW){
                                e_state = BLINK_PRESSED;
                            }
                            break;

                        case BLINK_PRESSED:
                            while(PB_PRESSED()){ //As long as PB is pressed, LED toggles per step4
                                LED1 = !LED1;
                                DELAY_MS(250);
                            }
                            e_state = STATE_RELEASED5;
                            break;

                        case STATE_RELEASED5:
                            if(PB_RELEASED()){ //PB is released step4
                                e_state = STATE_PRESSED4;
                            }
                            break;

                        case STATE_PRESSED4:
                            while(PB_PRESSED()){ //PB is pressed and held, led toggles step4
                                LED1 = !LED1;
                                DELAY_MS(250);
                            }
                            e_state = STATE_RELEASED6;
                            break;

                        case STATE_RELEASED6:
                            if(PB_RELEASED()){ //PB is released and pressed and held again step4
                                while(PB_PRESSED()){
                                    LED1 = !LED1;
                                    DELAY_MS(250);
                                    if(PB_RELEASED()){ //step4 PB if released
                                        e_state = STATE_RELEASED7;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            break;

                        case STATE_RELEASED7:
                            while(1){
                                LED1 = !LED1;
                                DELAY_MS(250); //delay of 250ms
                                if(PB_PRESSED()){ //PB is pressed last step
                                    e_state = STATE_RELEASED8;
                                    break;
                                }
                            }

                        case STATE_RELEASED8:
                            if(PB_RELEASED()) {
                                e_state = STATE_RELEASED1;
                            }//PB is released last step
                            break;

                        default: //default case
                            ASSERT(0);
                    }
   ```

Please help in identifying the root cause of the problem. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have not told us what the problem is - how does it behave if not as expected? 
While-loops and delays in state-machines is a design issue. You should not have the while loop at all, you should reenter the state, check the time elapsed and toggle the LED if it is time or change state if the button is released.  You also have no switch de-bounce - you probably need something more sophisticated than that `PB_PRESSED()` macro.

Comment: Why do you not define `PB_RELEASED()` as `!PB_PRESSED()`?  Why do you even bother to define both?

Comment: Actually, in `RELEASED_4`, you wait until the button is released, and `SW == 1` you got to `BLINK_PRESSED`. But, here, the while loop condition is not executed, because the button was just released and therefore the `PB_PRESSED()` is false. That's why, the it goes straight to the next state, without the LED blinking. And that same thing is in the other following ones .. the `RELEASE_6` even worse, how should the `if (PB_RELEASED()) { while(PB_PRESSED()) .. ` actually work? How can it be released and pressed at more or less the same time?

Answer (score 0):

You have not been exactly clear with respect to how it is not working as expected, but your approach to state-machine design is flawed, and you have not delat with switch bounce.

Given a function returning time elapsed in milliseconds, such as:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h>

uint32_t time_ms()
{
    return (clock() * 1000ULL) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
}
```

... your system may already have a suitable function to use instead.

And a debounced button function such as:

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool button_pressed()
{
    #define DEBOUNCE_MS 25ul
    static uint32_t timestamp = time_ms() ;
    static bool debounced_state = (_RB13 == 0) ;

    bool current_state = (_RB13 == 0) ;

    if( current_state != debounced_state &&
        time_ms() - timestamp >= DEBOUNCE_MS )
    {
        debounced_state = current_state ;
    }

    return debounced_state ;
}
```

The `BLINK_PRESSED` :

```
case BLINK_PRESSED:
{
    if( button_pressed() )
    {
        if( time_ms() % 250 )
        {
            LED1 = !LED1 ;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        e_state = STATE_RELEASED5;
    }
}
break ;
```

and similarly for other states with ill-advised wait loops.

The problem with the wait-loop is you cannot responds to other events that may cause a change state while you are in that state.  The only event that can cause a change of state is a button release and the only state you can then enter is the `STATE_RELEASED5`.  It makes the state-machine rather redundant as everything runs in a linear fashion and can represent only a very limited form of state-machine that is essentially merely a sequence.

Comment: The problem is in the case statement BLINK_PRESSED, the code I have builds and flashes on to the micro controller fine, everything executes fine until the BLINK_PRESSED state, its just that when I reach the BLINK_PRESSED state, I expect the while loop to blink the LED continuously until the PB_RELEASED() makes the condition false and then exits the while loop and move on to the other states . But, what happens is, in the BLINK_PRESSED state, LED just stays ON continuously rather than blinking and the logic does not execute.

Comment: However, I tested the logic in MPLAB Sim by toggling the inputs of the state machine which checks out the logic but fails to run it in real time on the HW. Hope this clearly explains the issue. Thanks much for your response.

Comment: @KungPao : You need to update your question with the missing information, not hide it in comments.  Your simulator has no switch bounce - that may be your problem in the real world.  I suspect that you are not in the state you think you are in and the states as they are make little sense.

Comment: @KungPao : moreover if you change the input state whilst stepping the code rather then asynchronously and in real-time you can of course force it to go through the states and remain in them as you expect. but in real time you are expecting the button to be both pressed and released at the same time!

Comment: I agree with you regarding the debounce delay but without debounce also, while loop should still work even if it misses a first few checks waiting for PB input to be set and start blinking after that. But it never blinks the LED. I also tried putting in some  normal code before the while loop in the BLINK_PRESSED state example LED1 = 1; DELAY_MS(250); LED1 = 0; and I can see the LED blink once in BLINK_PRESSED state but as soon as the while loop is hit, the LED freezes on and that's it.

Comment: @KungPao but it remains a flawed design.  Fix the obvious problems first.  Clearly the button state or loop break condition is not what you believe it to be at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You should slightly modify your state machine, which is quite fine.

It is ok to loop over and over and execute only one case every time. But you should do two things:

1. Debounce the key. For example with a counter and a small delay.
2. Read the key state **outside** the machine state, and just in one place.

Something like this:

```
loop forever:
  delay 1 ms
  if key_pressed {  // hardware read, just in a single place
    if keydebounce<5 keydebounce++
  } else {
    if keydebounce>0 keydebounce--
  }
  // now you have keydebounce which is: ==5? pressed - else not
  switch (machinestate) {
    ...
  }
```

If you want to flash the LED, write a state for that and use a counter incremented every ms. The "flashing" state waits until the counter reaches a values, then resets it, inverts the led and goes on. And of course it check if the state should be changed again.

Your code could be corrected in other ways, but now it is a hybrid between a state machine and a sequential machine...

The debouncing can be made differently, for example in interrupt by a timer so there are no delays and you don't waste CPU power, and the LED blinking also, so again you don't waste cycles doing nothing, but the important thing is that every button change leads to a single state machine change.

Or put it in another way: if the button changes the state of the machine, you must *assume* in the new state that the button has not changed again. When it will do it again, you will change state again. Perhaps I am not very clear but, if so, I can try to do better.